# notifee-react-native v7.8.0 giving error Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, react-native

React Native Version - 0.65.1

When I am pressing on notification I am getting below error.

error [Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference]

This is the code I am using for invoking notification.

```
const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
  id: 'channel101',
  name: 'CSutra Channel',
});

 RNFS.writeFile(newPath, encoded_string, 'base64')
      .then(async val => {
        console.log('came till here')
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('FILE_PATH', newPath);
        // Display a notification
        await notifee.displayNotification({
          title: 'Downloaded',
          body: `${
                  newPath.split('/')[newPath.split('/').length - 1]
                }`,
          android: {
            channelId
          },
          data: {
            myCustomData: 'custom officer'
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('some hopping')
        Toast.show({
          text1: `File download Failed`,
          position: 'top',
          visibilityTime: 6000,
        });
      });
    return 1;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('value of error', e)
  }
```

updated react-native version to 0.70.0 but still the issue persist